# Java Xml Transformation escapes surrogates code units that represents supplementary characters

Tags: java, xml, surrogate-pairs

I am executing a web application in the container of servlets Tomcat 8.0. In a request i try transforming an input data, to XML with code below. The firts input data character is a unicode supplementary character U+16980 represented as the char pair \ud81a\udd80, and the second character is another supplementary character U+16990 represented as the char pair \ud81a\udd90.

```
    String text = "    �  �";
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

    Element root = document.createElement("root");
    document.appendChild(root);
    Element node = document.createElement("sofa");

    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

    root.appendChild(node);

    Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(document);

    // create StreamResult for transformation result
    javax.xml.transform.Result result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("text.xml"));

    // create TransformerFactory
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    // create Transformer for transformation
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    // transform and deliver content to client
    transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

I was expecting: `<root><sofa>&#92544;  &#92560;  �  �</sofa></root>`

But instead I get: `<root><sofa>&#55322;&#56704;  &#55322;&#56720;  � �</sofa>
</root>`

Comment: What you get is still the original 2-codepoint representation. Do you believe that is wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, but not expected. The reason was that i had Xalan library in my classpath and according
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance() and ordered lookup procedure, uses this Xalan implementation of  TransformerFactory. Change to system-default implementation, specifying
"javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory" system property, get the
expected results

Comment: So this library supports 4-byte Unicode? If it does not, then I really don't see why you expected a perfectly valid combo (2 successive 2-bit codepoints in the surrogate area) translated.